# What rank is Stack Exchange among the Internet?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Just out of curiosity, what rank is Stack Exchange among websites? Google is obviously number 1. Does Stack Exchange make the top 10 or even the top 20?

Comment: http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com

Comment: Top ten is wayy too hard, even for StackOverflow. Youtube, Tumblr, Pinterest, Facebook, Twitter, Wikipedia, LinkedIn, there's so many more.

Comment: Comparing to all sites is not really "fair", better compare to other Q&A sites, the most famous "rival" of Stack Exchange is quora.com which is ranked below Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?country=GLOBAL https://www.quantcast.com/stackexchange.com?country=GLOBAL

Comment: @BradLarson Hmm, why the big drop at the start of 2017?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think it "happens" every year, and due to [Christmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas), where many people are on holiday for week or two, so not really browsing programming sites.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Site analytics actually show an increase in traffic in 2017: https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics so either their measurements are bad, other sites became bigger at a faster rate, or both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Exchange is ranked 133rd globally and 82nd in the USA [as per Alexa rankings](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackexchange.com).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fef9H.png]

I think, it will be fair to compare top site within Stack Exchange Network, instead of just Stack Exchange for rankings. For example, [Stack Overflow](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com) is ranked 53rd globally and 49th in the USA which is higher than the parent Stack Exchange.

Also, many of the Stack Exchange website are accessed as sub domains, so you never know which are the top sites within Stack Exchange network unless the address searched for rankings is like: ***[SubSite.StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)*** .

You may also want to look at [similar question asked here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265787/which-stack-exchange-site-is-the-most-popular).